# lottery java problem using arrays and random

Tags: java

so im stuck on this program that generates 6 integers that are between 1-49 then store them in an array and display them in ascending order but they have to be unique numbers. After that the program has to ask the user for their 6 numbers then compare the random array to the user to see if there's 3 matches or more which prompts they've won the lottery, (assume they put unique numbers). i have to include a method called checkTicket which asks the user for their numbers and returns the number of matches with the random number. BTW im super new to java so pardon my coding skills. I cant seem to figure out how to compare the random array with the users arrays in the checkTicket method and keeping count how many are the same.  this is what i have so far.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class lottery
{ 
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Random rand = new Random ();  
        int [] lotto= new int [6];
        int count=0;
        checkTicket(lotto, count); 
        int num =0; 


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            num = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1); 
            for ( int j  = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (lotto[j] == num) 
                {
                    num = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
                }
            }
            lotto[i] = num;
        } 

        System.out.println("\n The lottery numbers:");
        System.out.println("\n--------------");
        for (int i=0; i< lotto.length; i++){
            System.out.print("\n"+lotto[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n--------------");

        if (count>3){
             System.out.println("\nYou have the winning ticket and this was the number of matches: " 
                +count);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("\nBetter luck next time! This was how many you got right: "+count);
    }

    public static int checkTicket (int [] lotto, int count){
        System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers between 1 to 49");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        count=0; 
        int [] user =new int [6];

        for ( int i=0;i<user.length;i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Number: ");

            user[i]= kb.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println(user[i]+" ");

            for (int j= 0; j<lotto.length; j++){
                if (user[i] == lotto[j])
                    count++;

            }
        }
        return count; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  Which concepts or parts of your code are you struggling with?

Comment: i just noticed i didnt even mention that. im struggling with comparing the random array with the users and sorting the random array in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues which I can see in your code are as follows:

1. You need to initialize the `lotto` array before calling `checkTicket`.
2. Passing `count` into `checkTicket` is of no use because you are initializing it again using the statement, `count=0;` inside `checkTicket`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] lotto = new int[6];
        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            num = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (lotto[j] == num) {
                    num = (int) (Math.random() * 49 + 1);
                }
            }
            lotto[i] = num;
        }
        int count = checkTicket(lotto);
        System.out.println("The lottery numbers:");
        System.out.println("--------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(lotto[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n--------------");

        if (count > 3) {
            System.out.println("You have the winning ticket and this was the number of matches: " + count);
        } else
            System.out.println("Better luck next time! This was how many you got right: " + count);
    }

    public static int checkTicket(int[] lotto) {
        System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers between 1 to 49");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int[] user = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Number: ");
            user[i] = kb.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < lotto.length; j++) {
                if (user[i] == lotto[j])
                    count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter 6 numbers between 1 to 49
Number: 10
Number: 20
Number: 30
Number: 40
Number: 15
Number: 25
The lottery numbers:
--------------
15 38 10 27 13 30 
--------------
Better luck next time! This was how many you got right: 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know I had to initialize lotto before calling the method, I will make sure to remember that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling checkTicket before you have initialized the lotto array.